# Fail to run 'execute(sqlcmd)' of sqlite3 using Python,Ubuntu

Tags: python, sqlite, ubuntu-16.04

I want to use sqlite3 to deal with data in Ubuntu with python. But I always failed and get errors. Codes related to database are as follows:

```
sqlite = "%s.db" % name
#connnect to the database
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite)
print "Opened database successfully"
c = conn.cursor()

#set default separator to "\t" in database
c.execute(".separator "\t"")
print "Set separator of database successfully"

#create table data_node
c.execute('''create table data_node(Time int,Node Text,CurSize int,SizeVar int,VarRate real,Evil int);''')
print "Table data_node created successfully"
node_info = "%s%s.txt" % (name,'-PIT-node')
c.execute(".import  %\"s\" data_node") % node_info
print "Import to data_node successfully"

#create table data_face
data_info = "%s%s.txt" % (name,'-PIT-face')
c.execute('''create table data_face(Time int,Node Text,TotalEntry real,FaceId int,FaceEntry real,Evil int);''')
c.execute(".import \"%s\" data_face") % face_info

#get the final table : PIT_node
c.execute('''create table node_temp as select FIRST.Time,FIRST.Node,ROUND(FIRST.PacketsRaw/SECOND.PacketsRaw,4) as SatisRatio from tracer_temp FIRST,tracer_temp SECOND WHERE FIRST.Time=SECOND.Time AND FIRST.Node=SECOND.Node AND FIRST.Type='InData' AND SECOND.Type='OutInterests';''')
c.execute('''create table PIT_node as select A.Time,A.Node,B.SatisRatio,A.CurSize,A.SizeVar,A.VarRate,A.Evil from data_node A,node_temp B WHERE A.Time=B.Time AND A.Node=B.Node;''')

#get the final table : PIT_face
c.execute('''create table face_temp as select FIRST.Time,FIRST.Node,FIRST.FaceId,ROUND(FIRST.PacketsRaw/SECOND.PacketsRaw,4) as SatisRatio,SECOND.Packets from data_tracer FIRST,data_tracer SECOND WHERE FIRST.Time=SECOND.Time AND FIRST.Node=SECOND.Node AND FIRST.FaceId=SECOND.FaceId AND FIRST.Type='OutData' AND SECOND.Type='InInterests';''')
c.execute('''create table PIT_face as select A.Time,A.Node,A.FaceId,B.SatisRatio,B.Packets,ROUND(A.FaceEntry/A.TotalEntry,4),A.Evil from data_face as A,face_temp as B WHERE A.Time=B.Time AND A.Node=B.Node AND A.FaceId = B.FaceId;''')

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

These sql-commands are right. When I run the code, it always shows `sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error`. So how to change my code and are there other errors in other commands such as `create table`?

Comment: Please give us the full traceback, not just a short description of the exception. That will tell us which of these many lines of SQL is failing, and where in the string it's complaining.

Comment: Also, how do you know "These sql-commands are right"?

Comment: Actually, as pasted, this gets a `SyntaxError` from Python and won't run at all. You have unescaped double-quotes inside double-quoted strings, which means things like `\t` aren't inside strings, which is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

You have many problems in your code as posted, but the one you're asking about is:

```
c.execute(".separator "\t"")
```

This isn't valid Python syntax. But, even if you fix that, it's not [valid SQL](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).

The "dot-commands" are special commands to the `sqlite3` [command line shell](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html). It intercepts them and uses them to configure itself. They mean nothing to the actual database, and cannot be used from Python.

And most of them don't make any sense outside that shell anyway. For example, you're trying to set the column separator here. But the database doesn't return strings, it returns row objects—similar to lists. There is nowhere for a separator to be used. If you want to print the rows out with tab separators, you have to do that in your own `print` statements.

So, the simple fix is to remove all of those dot-commands.

However, there is a problem—at least one of those dot-commands actually does something:

```
c.execute(".import  %\"s\" data_node") % node_info
```

You will have to replace that will valid calls to the library that do the same thing as the `.import` dot-command. Read what it does, and it should be easy to understand. (You basically want to open the file, parse the columns for each row, and do an `executemany` on an `INSERT` with the rows.)